# Calcular a média de um campo, em um ano específico, dentro de um período

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Eu estava estudando queries no mysql usando o banco de dados de demonstração Employees ([link](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db)), quando resolvi fazer uma pesquisa na tabela *salaries* do que seria um relatório do quanto a empresa gastou por ano com salários.

Tabela *salaries*:

> emp_no int(11) PK
>
> salary int(11)
>
> from_date date PK
>
> to_date date

from_date é a data em que um empregado começou a receber um salário e to_date é quando ele terminou de receber ele (ele foi despedido ou teve um aumento).

Supondo que um empregado recebeu um certo salário do ano de 2000 até 2005, como eu informo o banco de dados que ele deve ser incluído no calculo em todos os anos entre esses dois?

A pesquisa que eu fiz e que parece ter retornado o resultado que eu espero é (em parte) essa:

```
SELECT 1985 AS ano, AVG(salary) AS media FROM salaries 
WHERE 1985 BETWEEN YEAR(from_date) AND YEAR(to_date)
UNION
SELECT 1986 AS ano, AVG(salary) AS media FROM salaries
WHERE 1986 BETWEEN YEAR(from_date) AND YEAR(to_date)
UNION
...
```

Repitindo isso até o último ano.

Obviamente esse código não é boa, pois repete o mesmo SELECT e a mesma pesquisa (com o ano diferente) várias vezes, e nesse banco de dados cada um desses SELECTs nessa tabela demora 1,5 segundos.

Alguém sabe um jeito mais eficiente de se fazer essa pesquisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com certeza reparou que todas as suas queries seguem o mesmo padrão:

```
SELECT "ANO", AVG(salary) as media
  FROM salaries
 WHERE "ANO" BETWEEN YEAR(from_date) AND YEAR(to_date)
```

Criar uma forma genérica para um intervalo de anos é fácil e necessita apenas de uma tabela ou sub-query auxiliar com o intervalo de anos pretendido (isto é importante para garantir que, exista ou não informação para esse período na base de dados, o conjunto de resultados irá incluir todos os anos no seu relatório)

Uma forma genérica, usando uma sub-query para criar o intervalo de anos, é a seguinte:

```
SELECT ANOS.ANO, AVG(salary)
  FROM 
  ( 
         SELECT 2000 AS ANO UNION ALL
         SELECT 2001 AS ANO UNION ALL
         SELECT 2002 AS ANO UNION ALL
         SELECT 2003 AS ANO UNION ALL
         SELECT 2004 AS ANO UNION ALL
         SELECT 2005 AS ANO 
  ) ANOS
  LEFT JOIN salaries Sal
    ON ANOS.ANO BETWEEN YEAR(from_date) AND YEAR(to_date)
 GROUP BY ANO
 ORDER BY 1
```

Repare que é necessário introduzir a cláusula `GROUP BY YEAR(from_date)`, isto porque, ao contrário das suas queries em que a média era calculada individualmente para cada um dos anos, esta forma seleciona todos os registos válidos nos diferentes anos de uma vez só. A cláusula GROUP BY vai agrupar os registos com base em semelhanças entre eles, neste caso o ANO, e aplicar a função AVG a cada uma desses grupos.

Agora, um pormenor bastante importante. A solução anterior não vai devolver, muito provavelmente, o resultado correcto. O seu problema não é simples de resolver e depende também (e não só) da forma como a informação está guardada na base de dados:

- A informação na tabela salários representa o salário anual, mensal ou semanal?
- Os salários são pagos com que frequência? Ao mês, à semana?

Para ter uma ideia, imagine o empregado João que começou a trabalhar na empresa em Janeiro de 2000 até Dezembro de 2000, com salário pago mensalmente. Recebeu portanto 12 salários durante o tempo em que esteve na empresa.

- Inicialmente o seu salário anual foi de de 30'000$.
- 9 meses depois de ter começado, o seu salário aumentou para 60'000$.
- A empresa teve que pagar no total 9x2'500$ + 3x5'000$ para um total de 37'500$.

A solução anterior não considera esta mudança na forma como é calculada a média. Vai simplesmente somar estes dois montantes (30'000$ e 60'000$) como se tratando de dois empregados diferentes, inflacionando a média.

Para determinar o total gasto em salários, seria necessário primeiro calcular o gasto individual com cada um dos funcionários, tendo em consideração a periodicidade dos salários e qualquer alteração durante o ano e depois sim calcular a média.

Comment: Obrigado, isso ajudou bastante. Eu não tinha pensado nessa questão de que os salários mudam no meio do ano, agora eu vou ver um jeito de fazer essa pesquisa levando isso em consideração.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você precisa saber o salario médio do funcionario ano a ano. Se for isso,  é possivel utilizar o comando "group by"

ex:

```
SELECT YEAR(from_date) AS ano
     , AVG(salary)     AS media 
  FROM salaries 
 WHERE emp_no = ...
GROUP BY YEAR(from_date)
```

mais detalhes [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/exemplos-com-group-by-e-com-a-clausula-having-totalizando-dados-sql-server-2008-parte-2/19839)